# Add title to pandas histogram using "by" argument

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add a title to a histogram created using the pandas hist function on Series in case the "by" argument is used?

For a simple histogram no problem exists. Hence, the following works perfectly:

```
In [115]: runELMLearning.utime.hist()
Out[115]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x20aaa590>

In [116]: plt.title("fooo")
Out[116]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x228b8550>
```

However, when using the by clause this doesn't work anymore:

```
In [117]: runELMLearning.utime.hist(by=runELMLearning.state)
Out[117]: 
array([[Axes(0.1,0.763636;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.388889,0.763636;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.677778,0.763636;0.222222x0.136364)],
       [Axes(0.1,0.559091;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.388889,0.559091;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.677778,0.559091;0.222222x0.136364)],
       [Axes(0.1,0.354545;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.388889,0.354545;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.677778,0.354545;0.222222x0.136364)],
       [Axes(0.1,0.15;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.388889,0.15;0.222222x0.136364),
        Axes(0.677778,0.15;0.222222x0.136364)]], dtype=object)

In [118]: plt.title("fooo")
Out[118]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x13612b10>
```

Even though it doesn't indicate any error, the title is silently ignored.

Another strange observation I made is that when I create a figure first, and then use the hist function, in the case of the by argument, the first figure is ignored and the hist functions creates a new one, which I cannot find the gca of matplotlib. For simple histograms again no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found this on my own: I need to use suptitle from pyplot to add a title to a whole figure and not to individual axes, which is the case with the different histograms in subplots.

http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/title-when-using-subplot-td22151.html